# PyTorch DataLoader returns the batch as a list with the batch as the only entry. How is the best way to get a tensor from my DataLoader

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

I currently have the following situation where I want to use `DataLoader` to batch a numpy array:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.utils.data as data_utils

# Create toy data
x = np.linspace(start=1, stop=10, num=10)
x = np.array([np.random.normal(size=len(x)) for i in range(100)])
print(x.shape)
# >> (100,10)

# Create DataLoader
input_as_tensor = torch.from_numpy(x).float()
dataset = data_utils.TensorDataset(input_as_tensor)
dataloader = data_utils.DataLoader(dataset,
                                   batch_size=100,
                                  )
batch = next(iter(dataloader))

print(type(batch))
# >> <class 'list'>

print(len(batch))
# >> 1

print(type(batch[0]))
# >> class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

I expect the `batch`to be already a `torch.Tensor`. As of now I index the batch like so, `batch[0]` to get a Tensor but I feel this is not really pretty and makes the code harder to read.

I found that the `DataLoader` takes a batch processing function called `collate_fn`.  However, setting `data_utils.DataLoader(..., collage_fn=lambda batch: batch[0])` only changes the list to a tuple `(tensor([ 0.8454, ..., -0.5863]),)` where the only entry is the batch as a Tensor.

You would help me a lot by helping me finding out how to elegantly transform the batch to a tensor (even if this would include telling me that indexing the single entry in batch is okay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for inconvenience with my answer.

Actually, you don't have to create `Dataset` from your tensor, you can pass `torch.Tensor` directly as it implements `__getitem__` and `__len__`, so this is sufficient:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.utils.data as data_utils

# Create toy data
x = np.linspace(start=1, stop=10, num=10)
x = np.array([np.random.normal(size=len(x)) for i in range(100)])

# Create DataLoader
dataset = torch.from_numpy(x).float()
dataloader = data_utils.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=100)
batch = next(iter(dataloader))
```

Comment: I dont think you can pass a list of `torch.tensor` to `TensorDataset`, instead we can do like this `TensorDataset(x_tensor, y_tensor)`. But this still cannot figure out the issue that `batch` is a list.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, when I make the following change `input_as_tensor = [torch.from_numpy(row).float() for row in x]` and unpack this list `dataset = data_utils.TensorDataset(*input_as_tensor)`, `batch = next(iter(dataloader))`now returns a `list` of length 100. However, I would want a tensor of shape (batch_size, features), so in this example (100, 10). Only if my batch is a `torch.Tensor`, I can feed the data into a instance of, e.g., `torch.nn.Linear()`. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: @Auss Sorry for inconvenience, essentially you don't have to create any `Dataset` to work like you want it, see changed answer.